# SSD NVMe drive low write values

Tags: ssd, nvme

the drive is rated for up to 3,000MB/sequential write. But somehow I still getting low write speed values:

[image]

I checked in case the temperature was too high and was degrading the performance but it seems normal:

[image]

I did a fimrware update just in case and it didn't work out.

Comment: A few observations: You did not mention the make of your SSD. And two, you're almost out of space on the partition you're testing on. What's the total capacity of the SSD in question?

Comment: Corsair MP510.. 240GB total I had freed some space now is 52% empty ( 120 gb )...Still same results

Comment: How long have you used the SSD for? And in what conditions? Is it in an enclosure, an M.2 slot on the motherboard, and if so, what is the link width of the slot its' plugged in to? Details on your machine's form factor are also missing from your question.

Comment: Less than 6 months, main drive for the OS. Pluged into the motherboard ( MSI Gaming plus max ) NVMe support, up to 32 Gb/s using PCI-Express Gen3 x4, Supports STORE MI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you had the drive so full, you will lose speed until TRIM catches up. Every write at the moment has to do an erase first, which will almost halve your potential speed.

idk how to do it on Windows, but investigate manual TRIM options, perhaps in your SSD's setup/control panel.

Comment: Corsair MP510.. 240GB total I had freed some space now is 52% empty ( 120 gb )...Still same results – Jose Vieiros 8 mins ago

Comment: Yes. My answer was already based on your existing comment above. Deleting data will not immediately free up all the existing written sectors, it merely marks them as available to be overwritten..

Comment: Makes sense, how much I need to wait until the performance goes back to normal or there's a way to boost the process?

Comment: See the 2nd paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Yeah I made an "optimize" on windows but doesn't seems to change that much, will try to find another way

Comment: @JoseVieiros you've done what you can, now you have to wait. TRIM tells the drive controller that it can begin erasing blocks but it will happen during drive idle time and probably slowly at that. Constantly re-benchmarking it will simply re-allocate blocks and give the controller *more* to erase. Give it a day or two (possibly leaving the computer on but idle overnight) and *then* try benchmarking. Benchmarking it immediately is useless.

Comment: After several days, the software CrystalDiskMark still showing me the same results 3100 on reads / 260 on writes..... it is normal?